# nginx - sometimes serves previous versions of file (cached?)

Tags: nginx, caching, cache-control

My nginx server (installed by VestaCP) is serving cached content even though I'm telling it to not cache.
The file is a m3u8 file, created and updated constantly by ffmpeg.

nginx config:

```
location ~ /stream/(.*)\.m3u8 {
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;
    proxy_no_cache 1;
    proxy_cache_bypass 1;
    max_ranges 0;
    root /;
}
```

cURL command and output:

```
$ curl https://example.com/stream/klan.m3u8 -k -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 28 Apr 2018 18:43:42 GMT
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
Content-Length: 276
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Last-Modified: Saturday, 28-Apr-2018 18:43:42 GMT

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1049
...
```

As you can see on `#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1049`, it's on 1049th chunk on that request. It increases +1 in every ~5 second.

A few seconds later, same request, but output is:

```
..
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1050
..
```

I keep sending the same requests almost every second, and it sometimes it returns a decreased value, from previous file.

```
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1047
```

I've verified that there's no problem on the file. nginx returns a different file, cached version.
Also, if I use `echo file_get_contents("/stream/..");` in PHP, it also returns up-to-date file.

Any ideas how to debug it, or solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use `open_file_cache off;` apparently.